# What does .f mean in CGSize in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgsize

This must be in documentation somewhere but I cannot find it. What does the `.f` mean when defining rectangles using `CGSizeMake` as in `CGSizeMake(200.0f, 100.0f);`?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `CGSize`.

Answer (score 2):

.f means that value is `float`.
if you write directly `1.0` it is initialized as `double`.
to use less space `1.0f` is better.

Comment: what else could it be?

Comment: ok.  Thx.  will mark correct when it lets me!

Comment: It's not better to use the `.f` here. `CGFloat` may be a `double` or a `float` depending on the device. It's better to just use `1.0` instead of `1.0f`. Then the compiler can adjust the value as needed when compiling.

Comment: No matter what, the compiler will adjust the value. It's a compile-time constant. Any converting necessary will happen at compile time, too. It would be just as good to use an `int` for an integral value. Any of `1`, `1.0`, and `1.0f` will result in the same binary.

Comment: You are both right. thanks for clarification.